# Best way to save data to a file?

Tags: python

```
def saveFood():
    print('Enter food name')
    foodNameS = input().upper()
    print('Enter calories')
    foodCalS = input()
    print('Enter protein')
    foodProteinS = input()
    print('Enter fat')
    foodFatS = input()
    print('Enter carb')
    foodCarbS = input()
    print(foodNameS + '\n' + 'calorie ' + foodCalS + '\n' + 'protein ' +
          foodProteinS + '\n' + 'fat ' + foodFatS + '\n' + 'carbs ' + foodCarbS)
    print('Confirm? Y/N')
    while True:
        confirmation = input().upper()
        if confirmation == 'Y' or confirmation == 'N':
            if confirmation == 'Y':
                text_file = open(("FoodList.txt"), "a")
                text_file.write('' + "\n")
                text_file.write('\n' + 'Food: ' + foodNameS.lower() + "\n")
                text_file.write('cal ' + foodCalS + "\n")
                text_file.write('protein ' + foodProteinS + "\n")
                text_file.write('fat ' + foodFatS + "\n")
                text_file.write('carb ' + foodCarbS)
                text_file.close()
                askOption()
                break
            else:
                askOption()
```

this is currently my code in a calorie tracking app i have. However when deleting items from the list it becomes very awkward and ugly. I tried json but deleting and adding extra stuff was also weird and awkward. What can i do to tackle this? I tried shelve but it seemed inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would use f-strings for readability.

Here an example

```
report = f'''
Food: {foodNameS.lower()}
cal {foodCalS}
protein {foodProteinS}
fat {foodFatS}
carb {foodCarbS}
'''

with open("FoodList.txt", "a") as f:
  f.write(report)
```